# Set Theory Proof Verification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Theorem: Let A and B be sets such that A$\cup$B≠B and B\A={}. Then we have
>   that B$\subset$A

**Theorem is True.**

A and B are not identical sets.

A contains all of B's elements, therefore B is a subset of A.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see a proof here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps you could show me how to "prove" it then. Is my explanation correct however?

Comment: "$A$ contains all of $B$'s elements" — why?

Comment: Both your statements are correct.  But you need to explain why they are true.

Answer (score 1):

$A \cup B \neq B \implies \exists x \in A$ such that $x\notin B $

$B$ \ $A= \emptyset \implies \forall x \in B, x \in A \implies B \subseteq A$

but, since we showed before $\exists x \in A$ such that $x\notin B $, we can conclude $B \subset A$

Answer (score 0):

1) $X \cup X = X$ for all sets.  (This should be clear.  if x is in the union it is in one or the other.  As they are the same x is in X.  Likewise if x is in X then it is in the union of X and X.  So the set and the set unioned with itself is the same.

$A \cup B \ne B \implies A \ne B$

2) $B / A = \emptyset$.  Suppose $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$ then $x \in B / A$ which is a contradiction. so $B \subseteq A$ ... or $B = \emptyset$... which would mean $B \subseteq A$.  So $B\subseteq A$.

But $B \ne A$.  So $B \subset A$